# Перевод из XML в HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Возможно ли создать html файл, имея файл xml и таблицу стилей xsl, без строки подключения таблицы стилей в xml и каких-либо утилит? Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Вы можете сделать программно. Например, в c# или многих других языках.

Comment: Даже через *.bat файл. Какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: если без утилит, то можете распечатать xml и xsl и руками забивать html  читая эти два документа. :) а если серьезно, то все равно понадобятся использовать утилиты или прописывать стиль в xml

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть множество возможностей, самое простое использовать конвертор, например онлайн (https://onlineconvertfree.com/ru/convert-format/xml-to-html/), но качество будет на 4-ку, лучше все ровно не сделать.